# How do I make an archived-dump of my site?

Tags: 8, drush

I have multiple versions of drush and cannot make an archive-dump of my site.

**drush8 ard**/**drush8 archive-dump** returns

> [error]  The drush command 'ard' (and/or 'archive-dump') could not be found.  Run `drush
>   cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
>   installed new extensions.

**drush6 ard**/**drush6 archive-dump** returns

> Drush 6.6.0 does not support Drupal . See
>   http://drupal.org/project/drush for more information.
>   [error] Command archive-dump needs a higher bootstrap level to run -
>   you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal
>   environment to run[error] this command. The drush command
>   'archive-dump' could not be executed.

**drush ard**/**drush archive-dump** returns

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not
>   found in /var/www/mywebsite/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 60

---

**drush8** = * remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git

**drush6** = * remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git

**drush** =  Drush Version:6.2.0

---

If I run **drush8 status** on my local site it returns

> Drush:9.0-dev-g9bbddb2

If I run **drush6 status** on my local site it returns

> Drush 6.6.0 does not support Drupal . See http://drupal.org/project/drush for more information.

If I run **drush status** on my local site it returns

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /var/www/mywebsite/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 60
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                         [error]
>   Error: Class 'Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface' not found in /var/www/mywebsite/core/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 60

Comment: PHP 5.6.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)

Comment: Only Drush 8+ supports Drupal 8. [Drush install docs](http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/)

Comment: this is exactly the mental nudge I needed. I went back into drush8 and checked out the 8.x version of drush and it works as expected.

Comment: Please highlight this in your post, so people won't have to read in the comments!

Comment: @ponies You should make your comment an answer, so the question doesn't show up in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Drush 8 supports: Drupal 7->8.3
- Drush 10 supports: Drupal 8.4->9

The Drush\Drupal Compatibility chart: https://www.drush.org/latest/install/#drupal-compatibility

Drush 8 is expected to go end of life with Drupal 7 in November 2022.

More information about `ard` in drush 9: https://github.com/pantheon-systems/documentation/issues/3946#issuecomment-467963427